# Suddenly not sore anymore?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, workout, weight-gain, abdominals

I began tranining split training 3 months ago, about 4 days a week.

I am normally SO SORE after every workout and have been making gains in strength and size.

I took about 2 weeks off from the gym and ever since getting back into it...
I do not get sore?
And I am doing basically the quantity and duration as what ive always done.
about 4 exercises with 3 sets per exercise about 10 reps.
Yesterday I did a killer ab workout, so many different exercises and even an ab circuit, and trained shoulders pretty hard (which I don't train that often) and feel nothing today? same has been happening lately when I train abs and such?

My ab workout is quite lengthy and do incorporate increasing weight to my ab workout.... Am I just getting used to it or do I need to switch up my workout?

Comment: I have often wondered about this myself. I read articles about the relationship between workout and soreness. Is it possible to work a muscle you never did before and not be sore? And why? Could it be a sign of health not to be sore?  I didn't see anything online that answered my questions.

Answer (score 8):

Soreness does not mean that you had a good workout (or vice versa), it means you had a workout you weren't used to. I've been lifting for a few years and I never feel sore, except for when I've had a long time off.

Comment: In respects to weight lifting, soreness DOES mean you have had a productive session. Lack of soreness means that there was absolutely nothing done to stimulate growth.

Comment: That's certainly not true. Lots of people, including me, rarely get sore at all, and we still get results. The only time I get sore is when doing excentric, static or otherwise "unusual" exercises.

Answer (score -1):

Soreness has to do with micro tears in the muscle fibers themselves. Strenuous activity, whether it is purposefully done via  exercise or through another manner is not relevant. Once these tears occur, you take in macronutrients and rest to rebuild the muscle and bind these micro-tears. With time and dedication via diet and exercise your muscles will get stronger and larger. However, as common sense dictates, you will have to increase your workload [reps, weight, etc] to keep the tears coming and the cycle going.